# Drupal Node Hierarchy

Tags: drupal-6, cck, taxonomy, pathauto

I'm having a problem working out how drupal structures content.

I have a content type called "Artists" and then i have "Songs" i want my URL's to be:

```
www.foo.com/{artist generated url}/{song generated url}
```

i.e.

```
www.foo.com/led-zeppelin/stairway-to-heaven/
```

{artist generated url} -> is created automatically by pathauto from the title of the content type
{song generated url} -> s created automatically by pathauto from the title of the content type

inside the content type of "song" there is a CCK field for "Node Reference" which refrences Led Zeppelin.

That's as far as i got :) so now the question is how to get the URL structure as i want, for right now i only get:

```
www.foo.com/led-zeppelin/
www.foo.com/stairway-to-heaven/
```

Which sucks :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, in pathauto settings you can use the linkurl-raw for the node referenced.